# MVC - EF Binding not working on update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, binding, automapper

This is driving me insane. I will go step by step.

This is my model:

```
public class Debate : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team1 { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team2 { get; set; }

    //Problem here.
    public virtual Cathegory Cathegory { get; set; }
```

}

This is my ViewModel (when Edit)

```
public class DebateEditVm : BaseVm
{
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public  TeamVm Team1 { get; set; }

    public  TeamVm Team2 { get; set; }

    //The Value of the selected one.
    public Guid Cathegory { get; set; }

    //List of different cathegories. I show this in the view with a @Html.DropDownListFor
    public List<CathegoryVm> Cathegories { get; set; }

    public DebateAltaVm()
    {   
        Team1 = new TeamVm();
        Team2 = new TeamVm();
    }
}
```

In my Edit (Post) I have the following.

```
          public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include =   Id,Title,Description,Team1,Team2,Cathegory")] DebateEditVm debate)
    {
            //Automapper from VM to MODEL
            var debateEntity = Mapper.Map<Debate>(debate);

            //Either with this commented or not wont Update the Cathegory of the debate!!!!!!!!
            //debateEntity.Cathegory = Db.Categorias.Find(debateEntity.Cathegory.Id);

            Db.Entry(debateEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.Entry(debateEntity.Team1).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.Entry(debateEntity.Team2).State = EntityState.Modified;

            Db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(debate);
    }
```

Automapper settings

```
       Mapper.CreateMap<Debate, DebateEditVm>()
             .ForMember(m => m.Cathegory, opt=>opt.MapFrom(m=>m.Cathegory.Id));


        Mapper.CreateMap<DebateEditVm, Debate>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Cathegory, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(vm => new Cathegory {Id = vm.Cathegory}));
```

So the new VALUE is binded to the VM and when I try to update the Debate all changes are good except for Cathegory (I tried also with commented lines)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`ResolveUsing` is for using custom value resolvers. I've only ever seen the generic version used, i.e. `ResolveUsing<MyCustomValueResolver>(...)`, so I'm not sure what exactly is happening when no custom value resolver is provided. However, generally speaking, the way this works is that the value you pass in is not the value returned, but merely what is passed to the value resolver. The value resolver, then does something with what was passed in and returns that.

Long and short, it looks like you should just be using `MapFrom` here:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DebateEditVm, Debate>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Cathegory, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => new Cathegory { Id = src.Cathegory }));
```

While we're here though, one thing. Don't use the `Bind` attribute, really ever, but especially when you're already using view models. The whole entire point of a view model is to present only what is necessary to the view, so `Bind` should be totally unnecessary. Further, since the nature of a view model is that you are going to have to move the data from it onto your entity, you can then control explicitly what is and isn't allowed to be modified. The entire purpose of `Bind` is to prevent users from being able to modify properties they shouldn't, but there's no way period to do that with a view model, unless *you* allow it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris, I made that change but everything gets updated excelt the Cathegory... I am about to quit! :(

Comment: Actually, I think it's your `Bind` attribute, which like I said, is completely pointless anyways. However, if you're going to use it, you have to be explicit about every single property. That means including `Cathegory.Id`, not just `Category` in that list, and so on and so on.

Comment: I removed the Bind attribute and no change. I don't know what else to check.